# Proceeds from a law suit and taxes

Tags: united-states, securities, income-tax

Suppose that an investor has owned the XYZ stock for a long period of time. It is then taken over by the ABC company and the investor has a long term capital gain. A couple of years later, a class action suit occurs and it is determined that the ABC company did not pay enough for the  XYZ company. The investor then receives money from the law suit. I claim that money is taxable as a long term capital gain. Am I right?

Note: XYZ and ABC are fictional companies that  I made up.

Comment: "couple of years later" is bad: the statue of limitations for most crimes that could determine such are only 2-5 years.

Comment: All income is taxable - whether its a capital gain requires a deeper understanding of the tax code than I have.

Comment: @DaleM Can you tell me what area of the tax code to look at?